# How can i pass a generic class as param to Intent constructor

Tags: java, android, generics

I have this generic activity in my android application

```
public class NavegadorActivity<T> extends Activity {

    ....
...
}
```

And I'm trying to call it as below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NavegadorActivity<Clientes>.class);
```

However, Intent constructor doesn't accept a generic class as param. Then I tried this code

```
Class<NavegadorActivity<Clientes>> NavClientes =  NavegadorActivity.class;

Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NavClientes.class);
```

Which doesn't work either.

Nor this

```
Class<NavegadorActivity<Clientes>> NavClientes =  NavegadorActivity<Clientes>.class;

Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NavClientes.class);
```

Anyone know how can i pass a generic class as param to Intent constructor?

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity , why are you using generic activity ?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the `Intent` constructor; the problem is that your syntax is wrong. `NavegadorActivity<Clientes>.class` is not valid syntax (since you can't combine generics with `.class`), and neither is `NavClientes.class` (since `NavClientes` is a variable-name, not a type-name).

Comment: (There's also a conceptual problem with what you're trying to do. If `stringList` is an `ArrayList<String>` and `intList` is an `ArrayList<Integer>`, then `stringList.getClass()` and `intList.getClass()` will be the *same* instance of `Class`. You simply cannot use `Class` to pass in generic type information, because that information is erased at runtime.)

Comment: @Mr.Me I'm trying to do a datagrid in NavegadorActivity that show objects of T

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that android Intent System supports `Generic` activities and you shouldn't just create an activity object your self. I suggest to add an inner class to your activity that represents the generic functionality and pass that generic name via

```
intent.putExtraString("class", yourClass.getName());
```

and retreive that class object via

```
Class<?> myGeneric = Class.forName(intent.getStringExtra("class", "java.Object");
```

Comment: With this I get an other problem, in NavegadorActivity I need to declare another generic object DbAdapter<T> but myGeneric  is a class and I can't convert it in a Type again.

Answer (score 1):

what's wrong with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NavegadorActivity.class);
```

Comment: How the constructor of NavegadorActivity will deal with T class?

Comment: It is unnecessary to show the constructor since it is a generic class and need to know what is the class T

Comment: @Heberfa: you asked how to pass the `Class` object representing `NavegadorActivity` to the `Intent` constructor. There is just one `NavegadorActivity` class object at runtime, which can be accessed using `NavegadorActivity.class`. This answer answers your question. Constructor of NavegadorActivity has nothing to do with the question