# How can I convert a Class<?> in a Type?

Tags: java, generics

I have this code in my android application:

```
String objclassname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ObjClass");

Class<?> ObjClass = Class.forName(objclassname);

dbListView.setAdapter(new DbAdapter<ObjClass>(getApplicationContext(),ds,campos));
```

But it gives error because ObjClass is not a Type.
And

```
String objclassname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ObjClass");

Class<?> ObjClass = Class.forName(objclassname);

dbListView.setAdapter(new DbAdapter<ObjClass.getClass()>(getApplicationContext(),ds,campos));
```

gives error too.

And I Can't use generics due it: [How can i pass a generic class as param to Intent constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554874/how-can-i-pass-a-generic-class-as-param-to-intent-constructor)

How can I convert a Class in a Type?

ps.: Edited to be more clearly

Comment: `Class<?>` is a type `ObjClass` is a variable. `String`, `Integer`, `Double`, ... are also types. I think you need to learn some more basic Java.

Comment: Whenever you find yourself wanting to use a `Class` in generics, what you want to do is equivalent to an unchecked cast, so don't bother using the `Class`.

Comment: I think type erasure might make this impossible

Comment: Ok @BheshGurung but ObjClass.class or ObjClass.getClass() don't work too.

Comment: `ObjClass.getClass()` happens at runtime, but generics is enforced (only valid) at compiletime.

Comment: "_ObjClass.class or ObjClass.getClass() don't work to..._" `ObjClass.class` and `ObjClass.getClass()` are both instances of class objects.... **NOT** types.  Examples of types (as Bhesh Gurung has pointed out) are: String, Integer, Double, Class, Object.  You keep talking about _instances_ of objects of those types.  There's a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
String objclassname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ObjClass");

Class<T> ObjClass = (Class<T>) Class.forName(objclassname);

dbListView.setAdapter(new DbAdapter<T>(getApplicationContext(),ds,campos));
```

but you need to parametirize the method such as

```
public <T> void doSomething (String className)
```

Comment: But then it defeats the purpose of your idea).

Comment: If I use generics I don't need pass "ObjClass" in Intent

Comment: Exactly. What i mean is generics is used for compile time, so even if something like you mentioned worked it defeats the purpose of generics, since you still have a string for which a class is looked up, that already throws an exception. So I would refrain from generics here.

Comment: But I can't use generics due it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554874/how-can-i-pass-a-generic-class-as-param-to-intent-constructor

Answer (score 0):

Generics is a purely compile-time utility, only used for compile-time type checking. Generics don't affect what the code does at runtime. `ObjClass` is a variable whose value is only known at runtime. Therefore, it is useless for Generics, since it is not available at compile time. So Generics is not useful for you.

Since you cannot use generics to help with type checking, depending on your requirements (I have no idea what these `getApplicationContext(),ds,campos` things are), you can just pick an arbitrary type parameter:

```
new DbAdapter<Object>(getApplicationContext(),ds,campos)
```

(or in Java 7, `new DbAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),ds,campos)`)

or use the raw type (not recommended):

```
new DbAdapter(getApplicationContext(),ds,campos)
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be work for you

```
Class myclass = Class.forName("package.classname");
Object o = myclass.newInstance();
```

Yes this run but as said @jahroy isn't our problem.

Comment: yes and I've undrestand my error. I've edited the post to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: Read the question again, i need pass myclass type to build a new generic obj

Comment: @Heberfa - I believe the only way you'll be able to do that is to make your method (or class) generic and let it determine the type parameter based on some parameter that is passed to it.  I'm not familiar with `getIntent()` or `getExtras()` (I assume they're Android related), so I'm not sure whether this will be possible or not.  I can't tell what `getString("ObjClass")` is doing.  The bottom line is that you need to do some more reading on how generics work.  Generics and type parameters are far easier to use when you understand them (in stead of trying random things that don't make sense).